# googleapis node module causes React compile to fail

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets

I am trying to use Google Sheets in a Node/React application.  However, the application fails to compile.

This seems to be a known issue, but I can't seem find a proper, documented workaround.

Replicating the problem is easy, use npx create-react-app, add the googleapis module and add the import statement:

```js
import "./App.css";

import { google } from "googleapis";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Google Sheets</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This results in the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/googleapis-common/build/src/http2.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'http2' in 'C:\Users\ricks\Documents\node-sheets\node_modules\googleapis-common\build\src'
```

Comment: As workaround you can consider to include http2 in your package.json

Comment: `googleapis` is a Node module

Comment: [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) is described as "Node.js client library for using Google APIs. Support for authorization and authentication with OAuth 2.0, API Keys and JWT tokens is included.". That being said you can look at issues like https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2304 that has links to other issues.

Comment: I tried adding the deprecated http2 package, but it simply results in different error, also in webpack it looks like.

Comment: @squillman If I understand you, then as a beginner, I appear to have made a false assumption.  I assumed since React was built on Node, that Node modules would work in React apps.  That doesn't appear to be the case.  Some do not appear to be compatible with the WebPack build process, I guess.

Comment: React in and of itself isn't built on Node, it's pure javascript.  It can be confusing at first because create-react-app sets up your development environment to use npm, Webpack, and Node and Node is used as the http server for development in that scenario, but React can be manually set up without needing any of those.  Node modules need the Node libraries in order to have an execution environment.  Since React is independent of Node they won't be directly available to a Node module if you try to load it through React.